# SQL/Stored Procedure Issue

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have a situation, where I am executing a stored procedure and fetching results in my c# code which returns 55 records, now I have a column in the row which needs to be displayed as a result of executing another sql query. I have tried all means, but couldn't figure out how to achieve. Please help.

The C# code where I call the procedure which works fine is:

```
public static MonthlyFinancialReportCollection GetList(SASTransaction withinTransaction)
{
    MonthlyFinancialReportCollection records = null;

    using (DataSet ds = Helpers.GetDataSet("ShowPremiumCalcReport", withinTransaction))
    {
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            records = new MonthlyFinancialReportCollection();

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr[0].ToString())) 
                     records.Add(FillDataRecord(dr));                        
            }
        }
    }

    return records;
}
```

Now I want to run a query, against the called procedure in the above function, so it will fill the one of the column with calculated result of the query.

```
select 
    Sum(WorkingHours.WHO_Amount * dbo.PremiumLevel.PLE_Premium) as Snr_Teaching_Amt
from policy, policyline, coveroption,
     premiumlevel, WorkingHours
where policy.pol_id=policyline.pli_pol_id 
and   policyline.pli_cop_seniorteachingcoverid=coveroption.cop_id 
and   premiumlevel.ple_own_id=policy.pol_own_id 
and   premiumlevel.ple_sca_id=coveroption.cop_sca_id 
and   WorkingHours.who_pos_id=policyline.pli_pos_id
and   pol_dcsf=row["snr teaching staff"]`
```

Comment: You will call 55 times another Stored Procedure ? Can't you get all the Data with only one Stored Procedure ?

Comment: No, I can't as this first set of data gets generated with different criteria and its a pivot query, I tried injecting the query in first one but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slowest and easiest way:

- Make your second query a stored procedure which accepts "snr teaching staff"
  As a parameter.
- Add a new column to your DataTable from first query using:
  ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Snr_Teaching_Amt", typeof(decimal));
- Create a SqlCommand and a SqlParameter for the second stored procedure you created.
- Loop the DataTable and put  "snr teaching staff" in value of SqlParameter.
- Run the SqlCommand using ExecuteScalar, the returned value is the result of your second query which you can keep in your created column.

However I don't recommend this way because you'll have 55 + 1 server round trips which is not cool.

The in-between way:

Since your second query returns a single value, make the second query a Sql function. You can call it in the first procedure like:

```
SELECT *, dbo.MyFunction([snr teaching staff]) AS Snr_Teaching_Amt FROM ...
```

This will have better performance and is easier to maintain.
However I agree with Massanu, you can combine the procedures using sub queries. Best of luck ;-)

Comment: I think, this is good option, I will try and get back if issues. Thanks all.

Comment: I tried doing this and getting somewhere, can you check, whether it has any problems? 

     `using (DataSet ds = Helpers.GetDataSet  ("ShowPremiumCalcReport")) { foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) { using (DataSet ds1 = Helpers.GetDataSet ("ShowSnrTeachingCalc",withinTransaction)) { foreach (DataRow dr1 in ds1.Tables[0].Rows) { records.Add(FillDataRecord(dr,dr1)); }}}`

Comment: I think you're doing a bit of extra work :) ShowSnrTeachingCalc returns just a single value so you don't need to create or loop ds1.

Comment: To add the column:
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("SnrTeachingCalc", typeof(decimal));
Then in the first loop:
dr["SnrTeachingCalc"] = GetSnrTeachingCalc(dr["snr teaching staff"]);

GetSnrTeachingCalc is a method which simply calls the second sp you created. Lookup ExecuteScalar on MSDN for a sample.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue

**First Option**

```
 You execute the first stored procedure.
 Then foreach row 
    You execute the Second one with a parameter from the first one
 endfor
```

**Second Option:**

```
 You use a Cursor on the first stored procedure to get all the results in one call
```

Comment: Its not about running the stored proc into another one, the data which is generated as a result of first stored procedure, I want to run a second stored proc, that will fill the result data in one of the column of first result set. 

`
Acomb Primary School (2000) 295.20 NULL 1644.75 NULL
Applefields School  (7032) NULL NULL 12255.00 NULL
Archbishop of York's CE Junior School (3229) 410.40 NULL NULL NULL
Badger Hill Primary School (2431) 159.50 833.75 93.50 NULL
Bishopthorpe Infant School (2386) 605.00 NULL NULL NULL`

now in last column, I want to show the result of second query.

Comment: So you can Use the second Option with cursors. But you cannot call a stored procedure within a stored procedure so you will have to merge into a unique one.